# MYSQL syntax error on column alter

Tags: mysql, alter

i am trying to convert some Oracle sql cods to mysql, i got an issue here

```
ALTER TABLE RPT_ERRORLOG ALTER RUNDATE SET DEFAULT NOW();
```

it is showing an error 1064 like below

```
1 queries executed, 0 success, 1 errors, 0 warnings

Query: ALTER TABLE RPT_ERRORLOG ALTER RUNDATE SET DEFAULT NOW()

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOW()' at line 1

Execution Time : 0 sec
Transfer Time  : 0 sec
Total Time     : 0 sec
```

can anyone guide me to correct this code

thnx in advance

Comment: This is version dependent. Won't work in MySQL versions before 5.6.

Comment: Is there any alternative ... i mean any previous version codes are there    ....help me out from this problem

Answer (score 0):

Before MySQL version 5.6.x, a column of datatype `DATE` can only be assigned a *literal* value as a `DEFAULT` value.

(It's the `TIMESTAMP` datatype that allows for `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.)

---

With MySQL version 5.6.x, a column of datatype `DATE` can be declared with `DEFAULT NOW()`.